# Coloring OBShapedButton's(Custom Shaped Buttons) Image and Set it Again

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibutton, uicolor

I have some OBShaped/IrregularShaped custom buttons on the xib. I am setting the images of these buttons. Now I want to take the image of each button and color is according to some data and set it again. How can I do this?

I have tried using UIColor, UIImage+Tint.h, UIImage+ProportionalFill.h. But it's taking a lot of memory while coloring the high resolution images.

Comment: “Data formatters not available” is just a warning from GDB. It wouldn’t have anything to do with your issue.

Comment: This warning is affecting everything. Application crashes after getting this warn. I don't know why am I getting this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally did it with UIColor, UIImage+Tint.h, UIImage+ProportionalFill.h | :)